# maximum eigen value of a square matrix whose rows are normalized (2-norm) to 1

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a positive definite square matrix $A$ of size $n\times n$, with rows $A_i$, such that $||A_i||_2=1$. For such a matrix, I have checked that the maximum eigen value is upperbounded by $\sqrt n$

How do i prove this?

Note: We can add assumption of symmetric $A$ if required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=(a_{jk})$. That $A$ is  positive definite is not needed !

Let $ \lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ with $||x||_2=1$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$.

Then there is $j \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $|x_j|^2 \ge 1/n.$

It follows that with (Cauchy - Schwarz)

$$|\lambda| |x_j|=|a_{j1}x_1+...+a_{jn}x_n| \le ||A_j||_2||x||_2=1.$$

Hence

$$| \lambda| \le \frac{1}{|x_j|} \le \sqrt{n}.$$

Comment: Thanks! slick proof. I was able to come up with another proof using orthogonal eigen-vector basis, but i guess that's overkill. Thanks for showing the simple way out.